# Water level controller

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, circuit-design, short-circuit, circuit-protection

I want to design water level controller with PIC micro controller.

Simple working is: two inputs 1) tank_high and 2) tank_low which pulled up initially, and one wire will be connected to lowest point in tank which is dc ground.

The problem is PIC microcontroller is working on 5V DC and if accidentally in water tank ac phase, ac neutral or any high dc voltage dipped then it can fry out whole circuit. 
So how should I protect my circuit? Please give suggestions

Comment: why do you need a micro for that?

Comment: I can attach micro controller with Bluetooth, wifi etc so and I m not used to with logic ics that is why...

Comment: Is that circuit grounded? Or is it floating? (no I do not mean floating on the water, I mean floating voltage levels of power source). If it is floating than it shouldn't be a problem, it won't fry your circuit.

Comment: Oh common say something with sense ,clearly saying that voltage level is grounded but wire attached to it is floating in the water tank so it will sense any voltage probe we dip in to water ... That way I am asking ! And even how can we use any floating voltage level for digital input..?????

Comment: If you do not use electrical conduction for the sensing the level then there will be no problem. Also, putting a lid on the tank should go a long way to preventing other wires "accidentally" dipping in the tank.

Comment: If the power supply for the sensor is galvanically isolated, a single AC line in the water is not going to be an issue.   If you manage to get both AC wires in the water, you'll have more important things to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The one described here is built around timer NE555 and inverter buffer CMOS IC CD4049. It uses readily-available, low-cost components, and is easy to build and install on the over-head tank (OHT) to prevent wastage of water.[image]

The circuit works off a 12V battery or 230V AC mains using a 12V adaptor. The three sensors built from non-corrosive metal are fitted to the OHT as shown in Fig. 2 and connected to the circuit (Fig. 1) at appropriate terminals. Power supply terminal Vcc is at the bottom of the tank, sensor terminal L is just above the bottom of the tank and sensor terminal H is at the top of the tank. After you have properly installed the sensors in the OHT and connected the power supply, the circuit is ready to use.

Since Vcc terminal is at the bottom of the tank, when the water level falls below sensor L, timer IC2 is triggered at pin 2 via inverters N1 and N2 and its output goes high. As a result, the output of timer IC2 goes high. Relay RL1 energises and the motor starts filling water in the tank. The motor remains ‘on’ even when the water level crosses sensor L.
[image]
As water in the tank rises to touch sensor H, timer IC2 is retriggered at pin 6 via inverters N3 and N4 and as a result, its output goes low. The relay de-energises and the motor stops filling water in the tank. The motor remains ‘off’ even when the water level falls below sensor H.

As water is consumed and its level falls below sensor L, the motor restarts. Thereafter, the cycle repeats.

You can also manually start and stop the motor using switch S1.
[EFY Reference](http://electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/simple-automatic-water-level-controller)

Comment: Yes it is pretty traditional way sir ,but my question is what if 230v ac lines or like 50 v dc line dipped in to tank.. what could be the way for survive.. ?

Comment: If you know pure water does not conduct electricity. Any impurities, like salts, in the water enable it to conduct electricity. So, My answer will be **yes** it could cause damage whoever in contact with the water,. And regarding surviving, you can put an automatic circuit breaker (or my be fuse) to disconnect circuitry as soon as it detects excess current flow than expected.

Comment: An even simpler solution is to not connect 230 V AC or 50 V DC to the water!!  What's wrong with using low voltage, eg the 12 V supply line as suggested by the schematic?  AFAIK, the circuit should work fine with 5 V which is even safer than 12 V.   And the input and pull-down resistors can probably be increased to limit the current.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fuse or a circuit breaker, but that won't be guarantee. 
I once faced such a problem and used opto-electronics for the interface between the sensors and the processing circuitry.
See the attached image, you can separate the main circuit from the sensor inputs, so even in case of high current, the damage will be limited to the LED which can be easily replaced.[image] Also, the overall cost remains low as LEDs,LDRs and resistors used are less expensive than fuses and circuit breakers. Moreover, the cost of replacing a fuse is higher than replacing a LED.